# Repeater not working with export to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asprepeater

```
<asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export" OnClick = "ExportToExcel" />
```

this is my button to export

```
protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=RepeaterExport.xls");
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel.12";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        rpt1.RenderControl(hw);
        Response.Write("<table>");
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Write("</table>");
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

this is my code behind button but it is not working anything.

Comment: `but it is not working` could you provide more detail, what is not working.

Comment: there is nothing happening on button click

Comment: This code generates an HTML table, it doesn't export anything to Excel. The `xlsx` format is a ZIP package containing XML files.